# int to string on array - suggestions for this context

Tags: php, arrays, types

I have these arrays : $_POST['atlOriginal'] and $oldAtlPos. The values stored of both are this :

```
0   0
1   1
2   2
3   3
4   4
5   5
6   6
7   7
8   8
9   9
```

Now, if I done this comparison `$_POST['atlOriginal']===$oldAtlPos` it returns false, because  $_POST['atlOriginal'] values are Strings (the are passed trought GET/POST from client) and $oldAtlPos values are Integer.

What can I do here? What's the best strategy? Convert one in another?

P.S. I need to valutate the order of the values, so `===` is necessary;

P.S. 2 Values of Both will be stored in the database as Char(2);

**EDIT**

So :

```
for($i=0; $i<sizeof($oldAtlPos); $i++) echo $_POST['atlOriginal'][$i]."|".gettype($_POST['atlOriginal'][$i])." - ".$oldAtlPos[$i]."|".gettype((string)$oldAtlPos[$i])."<br/>";
```

will return :

```
0|string - 0|string
1|string - 1|string
2|string - 2|string
3|string - 3|string
4|string - 4|string
5|string - 5|string
6|string - 6|string
7|string - 7|string
8|string - 8|string
9|string - 9|string
10|string - 10|string
11|string - 11|string
12|string - 12|string
13|string - 13|string
14|string - 14|string
15|string - 15|string
16|string - 16|string
17|string - 17|string
18|string - 18|string
```

But seems that `if($_POST['atlOriginal']===(string)$oldAtlPos)` still return false...

Comment: You like to make your life harder, don't you ?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

If you are trying to compare them you could:

**use `==` instead of `===`**  *(recommended)*
`==` means 'do these values match'
`===` means 'do these values match *and* are they of the same type'

```
$foo['test'] = Array("1","2","3");
$bar = Array(1,2,3);
$baz = Array(3,2,1);

var_dump($foo['test'] === $bar); // FALSE - does not work
var_dump($foo['test'] === (string) $bar); // FALSE - does not work
var_dump($foo['test'] == $bar); // TRUE - works!
var_dump($foo['test'] == $baz); // FALSE - works because $baz is in a different order
```

`==` does **not** check key/value pair order *however* since you are only using values, the key is essentially the order and matches (so this does what you want)

From this above code, this is what the array **actually** looks like

**`$foo['test']`**

```
array(3) {
  [0]=>
  string(1) "1"
  [1]=>
  string(1) "2"
  [2]=>
  string(1) "3"
}
```

**`$bar`**

```
array(3) {
  [0]=>
  int(1)
  [1]=>
  int(2)
  [2]=>
  int(3)
}
```

`==` checks to make sure the key (the part in `[]`) and value (`int()` in this case) match, it does not check order -- **but this does not matter** since you are only using values and the key **is** the order.

The only time this would affect you is if you were using key/value pairs **and** wanted to check order such as:

```
// key/value pairs match but order does not
Array('1' => 'B', '0' => 'A') === Array('0' => 'A', '1' = 'B') // FALSE 
Array('1' => 'B', '0' => 'A') == Array('0' => 'A', '1' = 'B') // TRUE -- order is not checked
```

**Fix:** If you are using Key=>Value pairs then this will do the trick:

```
// Function to fix data
function array_fix(&$item, $key)
{
    $item = intval($item);
}

$foo['test'] = Array(1=>"1",2=>"2",3=>"3");
$bar = Array(1=>1,2=>2,3=>3);
$baz = Array(2=>2,1=>1,3=>3);

// str !== int
var_dump($foo['test'] === $bar); // FALSE

// Apply fix to all data in array
array_walk($foo['test'],'array_fix');

// int === int -- yay :-D
var_dump($foo['test'] === $bar); // TRUE
var_dump($foo['test'] === $baz); // FALSE - correct: out of order
```

Comment: Tried **cast the int to an string** (seems to be the best idea for my scenario), so I wrote `$_POST['atlOriginal']===(string)$oldAtlPos` as you suggested as well, but still return false... uhm...

Comment: You will probably need to do one of the last 2 methods (copy the array... or iterate the array...) -- the first 3 answers were before I realised you wanted to compare the array as a whole not just the values of the array

Comment: It works only if I wrote (string) on both, but is strange, $_POST['atlOriginal'] can't be int...

Comment: In fact, it is see as array. So what's about this? `(string)$_POST['atlOriginal']===(string)$oldAtlPos`

Comment: I'm guessing that is because $_POST['atlOriginal'] is an Array not a String. What does echo gettype($_POST['atlOriginal']) say?

Comment: What about: `array_walk($_POST['atlOriginal'], 'intval');` the data first then `if($_POST['atlOriginal'] === $oldAtlPos)` ?

Comment: At the end of the discussion, (string)$oldAtlPos wont convert the values from int to string; Just the type of the array. So I need to iterate all items :)

Comment: While a lot of these methods should work, what @hsz posted is correct and would be the most simple method of doing what you want...

Comment: Just see your last EDIT : `Array('1' => 'B', '0' => 'A') == Array('0' => 'A', '1' = 'B') // TRUE` I DON'T WANT THIS! The order must be respected :) So `===` is necessary for my context :)

Comment: But you're not using key => value pairs so it doesn't matter ? In your example you array is `Array(1,2,3,4,5,6,7,8,9,10,11,12)` etc. so it works. If you were using `Array(1=>'A', 2=>'B', 3=>'C')` etc it would be a problem, but you are not so == works fine :-)

Comment: From your question you are not using key=>value pairs, but just in case you are I posted an answer to that -- see my edit.

Comment: ahm....so Array('1', '2', '3')==Array('3', '2', '1') is false...and I just need `==`. I thought keys are always valutated :)

Answer (score 6):

Do not compare values with their types using `===`.

Compare just only values using  `==`.

**Edit:**

For example, there are:

```
$a = array(1, 2, 3);
$b = array('1', '2', '3');
```

and then when you compare those arrays in 2 ways (`==` and `===`), you will get following results:

```
$a == $b; // TRUE

$a === $b; // FALSE
```

So as you can see, what you need is to use `==` compare method.

**Edit 2:**

In your `P.S.` you say that you need to compare arrays order too.

It does it already. If you compare arrays like that you will get `false`:

```
$a = array(3, 2, 1);
$b = array('1', '2', '3');

$a == $b; // FALSE
```

Comment: I need` === TRUE if $a and $b have the same key/value pairs in the same order and of the same types.` I want to valutete the order!

Comment: @Pekka, you're right. However I've updated my answer with an example of arrays comparasion. I think, that is what markzzz wants.

Comment: so the official manual is wrong? http://www.php.net/manual/en/language.operators.array.php It says to use `===` : `TRUE if $a and $b have the same key/value pairs in the same order and of the same types.`

Comment: @markzzz Is there anything about that `==` is not checking order ? Have you tested my answer ? I had, I wrote for you the second `edit`.

Answer (score 1):

you have to iterate though each elements and compare them individually